# PHP não mostra os dados do array!

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Amigos, boa noite. No meu código, envio o seguinte:

```
function cadastrar(){
    var t = 0;
    var nome = $$("#nome").val();
    var cpf = $$("#cpf").val();
    var tel = $$("#telefone").val();
    var end = $$("#endereco").val();
    var medic = $$("#lista_medicamentos .item-inner");
    var medicamentos = [];

    medic.each(function(idx, li){
        t++;
        var id_med = $$(li).find(".item-id-"+t+"");
        var nome_med = $$(li).find(".item-title-"+t+"");
        var qnt_med = $$(li).find(".item-after-"+t+"");

        medicamentos.push(id_med.html() +' - '+qnt_med.html()); //cria o array
    })

    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('paciente', nome);
    form_data.append('cpf', cpf);
    form_data.append('telefone', tel);
    form_data.append('endereco', end);
    form_data.append('medicamentos', JSON.stringify(medicamentos));

    $.ajax({
        url: 'cadastrarP.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(response) {       
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(xhr.response);
        }
    }); 
return false;

}
```

No console, é enviado o dado da seguinte forma: (ID do medicamento - quantidade de saída)

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="medicamentos"

2 - 2,1 - 3
```

O que estou querendo fazer e tentando, é pegar o ID do medicamento, e a quantidade dele dispensada, e cadastrar na tabela dispensação. Tentei fazer um foreach, mas me retorna tudo numa linha só, sem a virgula: `2 - 21 - 3`

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
//header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');

include 'init.php';

if(isset($_POST['paciente'])){

    $paciente = $_POST['paciente'];
    $cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
    $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
    $endereco = $_POST['endereco'];
    $medicamentos = json_decode($_POST['medicamentos']);

    foreach($medicamentos as $val){
        echo $val;
    }
}
```

Como teria que ser feito esse foreach, para que apareça 2x no console.log?

Comment: tentou fazer o `$medicamentos = json_decode($_POST['medicamentos']);` depois `foreach ($medicamentos as $item => $value) echo $value->{'item_id'}`

Comment: Não, vou tentar!

Comment: @adventistaam Testei aqui, ainda assim não mostra nada no alert! =/

Comment: O que você quer mostrar no alert?

Comment: Porque esse script é apenas para mostrar o texto

Comment: Então, o que estou tentando fazer é: quando a pessoa clicar em cadastrar, separar o ID do medicamento, e a quantidade, e adicionar no BD, o ID e a QNT. Ainda não estou adicionando porque estou testando hehehe!

Comment: esses dados do medicamento estão em tabela ou onde?

Comment: Eles estarão numa tabela depois, mas no momento estão em 2 selects. Eles são enviados via ajax. É enviado o ID - QNT. Exemplo: ["1" - "2"]

Comment: Tenta assim `foreach($medicamentos as $val){
        $medic = explode("-", $val);
        $id = $medic[0];
        $qtde = $medic[1];
        echo "ID: ".$id;
        echo "Qtde: ".$qtde;
    }`

Comment: @adventistaam consegui resolver já. Estava com um erro no meu PHP. O retorno é daquele jeito mesmo que você disse. Muito obrigado!!

Comment: Que jeito? kkk falei tanta coisa ... Pra eu adicionar a resposta... Mas que bom que resolveu

Comment: Foi o primeiro jeito, me ajudou a encontrar a resposta. Mas faltou eu enviar o JSON.stringify no JQuery.

Comment: Legal. Muito bom!